# Laravel 5.3 Uploading in ubuntu16.04 nginx with command composer install --no-dev

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, frameworks

Everytime I run the command composer `install --no-dev`
I am getting this error, I am using maatwebsite in laravel as the error pointing out, I just don't know how to fix it.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   : Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in
>   /var/www/laravel/config/excel.php:18
>   2 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap
>
> /LoadConfiguration.php(60): require()
>
> ## 1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap
>
> /LoadConfiguration.php(38):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->l
>   oadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   Object(Illumina
>   te\Config\Repository))
>
> ## 2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Applicati
>
> on.php(203):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object
>   (Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
>
> ## 3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/K
>
> ernel.php(268):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
>
> ## 4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/K
>
> ernel.php(114): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->boo in
>   /var/www/laravel/co
>   nfig/excel.php on line 182 Script php artisan optimize handling the
>   post-install-cmd event returned with er
>   ror code 255

Update: 
This is the composer.json file content

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `composer.json` file?

Comment: @RossWilson I already added the content of my composer.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the reason you getting this error is because you're running `--no-dev` and you have `maatwebsite/excel` listed as a `require-dev` dependency.

You'll need to remove it as a dev dependency and then require it as a normal dependency and it should be fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats it. I just figure out that, I placed the the maatwebsite in require-dev portion, not in the require portion. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In the time you ask me to show the content of composer.json, I just fixed it. Coz I notice that, I placed it in wrong place. You the man. @Ross Wilson

Comment: @Mr.Unknown Glad I could help!